# How can I filter the content of listview when clicked a button?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview

I'm not using API or firebase yet, the data is stored locally.
here is my code
======>>

```
Widget _buildhouse(BuildContext contex, int index){
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

House house = houselist[index];   //houselist is the list of all houses

return GestureDetector(
  onTap: (){
   setState(() {]
     
    house = filteredhouse[index];  //this code wont be executed
   
     print(house.price);
   });
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DetailsScreen(house),));
  },
```

so those two lines that I commented on are the important ones I guess, the print code gets executed but not the other one. also if I say "house = filteredhouse[index];" at the beginning, I will get the filtered value. but it won't get changed when clicked the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by using this function void _filtered(){ setState(() { houselist = filteredhouse; }); } and then calling it inside of setState